# Getting "comparison of these types is not implemented" error while trying to compare two numbers in a list

Tags: r

I have a bubble sort function that looks like this:

```
print_sorted_array <- function(arr)
{
  len <- length(arr)
  for (i in 1:len){

    j <- i

    while((j > 1)){
      if ((arr[j] < arr[j-1])){
        temp <- arr[j]
        arr[j] <- arr[j-1]
        arr[j-1] <- temp
      }
      j <- j - 1
    }
  }
  return(arr)
}
```

When I try to call this function

```
print_sorted_array(list(5, 16, 8, 2))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in arr[j] < arr[j - 1] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
```

I tried debugging it but couldn't figure out the RStudio debugger as I'm very new to this. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, using as.integer() on both list elements in the if statement worked. Still don't know why it wasn't integer in the first place but stopped caring.